# Angular4 not showing correct result from get API

Tags: angular, rest

When I'm trying to get data from api with this code:

```
getUserRole() {
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.getToken()}`);
      console.log(this.getToken());
      const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});
      return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`).pipe(map(res => res.json()))
      .subscribe(data => {
      this.userRole = JSON.stringify(data);
        if (this.userRole === 'parent') {
          this.logout();
      } else if (this.userRole === 'school') {
        this.isUser = true;
        this.isAdmin = false;
        this.cookieService.set('isSchool', '1');
      } else if (this.userRole === 'admin') {
        this.isUser = false;
        this.isAdmin = true;
        this.cookieService.set('isAdmin', '1');
      }
      });
   }
```

I get `[]`, means blank array. But the same API when I try using postman, it gives the array filled like this:

```
[
    "Parent"
]
```

I doublechecked my api and confirmed, that everything seems ok, but I don't understand why I'm getting different result. Is there any problem with my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since angular6 has HttpClient by default, you dont have to call .json() explicitly

```
return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`).pipe(map(res => res))
```

also JSON.stringify is unecessary,

```
this.userRole = data;
```

**EDIT:**

You need to pass the headers in the put request aswell,

```
 return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL + this.loginApiRoot}/GetUserRoles`,options)
```

Comment: Response {_body: "[]", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …} This is what I am receiving now. see these "[]".

Comment: which means your request is wrong! check the network tab and compare with the postman request

Comment: Got through, if you notice the code, I've forgot to put options header in get request.

Comment: yeah! glad to hear it, but certainly you need to make those changes mentioned in the answer. upvote if this helped

Comment: I already did and yeah that helped. Can you pl edit your answer to mention what I forgot?

Comment: The question is about Angular 4 using `Http`, not `HttpClient`. Thus the statement that calling `.json()` isn't necessary is incorrect.